# Bryntum's Gantt Scheduler : How to load data from array instead of url

Tags: extjs, gantt-chart

I am very new to both extjs and Bryntum's Gantt.
In their sample example I found a file app/view/Viewport.js which have following code.

```
 var taskStore = this.taskStore = new MyApp.store.TaskStore({
            dependencyStore : dependencyStore,
            resourceStore   : resourceStore,
            assignmentStore : assignmentStore,
            url             : 'data.js'     // Some dummy data
        });
```

I think this code is responsible to load data.

But I want to load data from an array.Eg : arrTasks and not url.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var taskStore = this.taskStore = new MyApp.store.TaskStore({
        dependencyStore : dependencyStore,
        resourceStore   : resourceStore,
        assignmentStore : assignmentStore,
        root            : {
             expanded : true
             children : [
                { Id : 1, Name : 'Some Task' },
                ....
             ]


        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @mats...It worked...Would like to know if i want to load other store eg : dependencyStore from array how would i do that.

Comment: Thank @mats.One more question.I am implementing Bryntum's Gantt Scheduler and calling libraries and also have the licence but still I can see the licence warning in console.Do you know what could be the reason.

Comment: Cached files or you forgot to include the real licensed JS file